# What’s the problem with image rotation in context?

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, image-rotation

I have a small issue with rotating CGContext.

I have superview (A) UIImageView and its subview (B) also UIImageView. A - transformed (changed frame origin, scaled and rotated). When I’m trying to merge 2 images with CoreGraphics then I have some problems with rotated subview because when rotation = 0 then cgcontext drawn correctly.

What’s wrong here?

Video - https://streamable.com/s/3e4fx/tdjbtq

```
let transformedFrame = CGRect(origin: scaledOrigin, size: scaledSize).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians))

ctx.translateBy(x: transformeedFrame.width/2, y: transformedFrame.height/2)
ctx.rotate(by: radians)

fxOrigin.x -= transformedFrame.width/2
fxOrigin.y -= transformedFrame.height/2
```

Comment: "have some problems " What are you problems? Be very specific please